# Getting AVRDUDE flash progress state in java

Tags: java, avr, processbuilder, atmega, avrdude

I am trying to create a java UI for flashing/reading AVR ATMEGA controllers. 
I am able to do it by calling avrdude in Java ProcessBuilder with certain arguements.

But, I also want to get avr flashing progress state in java. I am only able to start the process and detects its finished state.

I also want to get the progress state of avr flashing in percentage or something which we are seeing when we run the avrdude in command prompt.

Any help ??

Thanks, 
Nikunj

Answer (score 0):

You can use the memberfunctions `getInputStream` and `getErrorStream` of the generated `Process` instance to grab the outputs of AVRDUDE.